# Passing command line arguments to commands

Tags: powershell, wmi

I need to pass a powershell script parameter to be part of a WMI query, however it's throwing errors.

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$user,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$pwd
)

$harryuser = Get-WmiObject -Namespace Root\Harry -ComputerName myserver -query "select * from 
UserList where name = $user"

harryuser.SetPassword($pwd)
```

Error is an invalid query

Answer (score 1):

Try adding single quotation around $user like this.

"select * from UserList where name = '$user'"